# Display Date from SQL in .NET

Tags: asp.net, date

I need to display a date value from my database in my page's textbox.

```
    Dim dbl As New vtisDAL.vtisDALDataContext
    Dim dsGetFacultydetails = From f1 In dbl.usp_GetFacultyDetails(Val(lblFacultyID.Text)).AsQueryable

    For Each entry In dsGetFacultydetails
        txtApprDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(entry.ApprovalDate).Date
    Next
```

When the column in table is empty, the textbox has value **00:00:00**. How do I display the box as empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if(Convert.ToDateTime(entry.ApprovalDate).Date.ToString().Contains("00:00:00")))
{
    txtApprDate.Text=string.Empty;
}
else
{
    txtApprDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(entry.ApprovalDate).Date.ToString();
}
```

or
Add this below line

```
 txtApprDate.Text= Convert.ToDateTime(entry.ApprovalDate).Date.ToString().Contains("00:00:00")?
                  string.Empty :  
                  Convert.ToDateTime(entry.ApprovalDate).Date.ToString();
```

instead of this line

```
txtApprDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(entry.ApprovalDate).Date
```

And I am not familiar in vb.net , So please convert this code to vb.net with yourself .

Comment: Will txtApprDate.Text="00:00:00:"; solve my problem? That's to display the textbox as EMPTY?

Comment: if `entry.ApprovalDate` is null it will give an error since you have used `.ToString()`

Comment: Sorry am just miss understand your question , Now I edited my answer @Aishvarya

Comment: @Shekhar , If the database column datatype is date-time ,then it's automatically not store null , it will be store 00:00:00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

you should check the **ApprovalDate** before converting it.

try this -

```
//It is in C#
txtApprDate.Text= String.IsNullorEmpty(entry.ApprovalDate.ToString())? "" :  Convert.ToDateTime(entry.ApprovalDate).ToShortDateString();
```

in place of -

```
txtApprDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(entry.ApprovalDate).Date
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem. My code goes like this.

```
        If (entry.ApprovalDate.ToString() = "") Then
            txtApprDate.Text = String.Empty
        Else
            txtApprDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(entry.ApprovalDate).Date
        End If
```

Many thanks to the people who helped me with this. :)